# Why does this lambda expression need a string cast to a string?

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda

Consider this method, which takes a dynamic object as an input parameter, then creates a string by stripping off non-numeric characters from the 'someProperty' property.

```
public static void Foo(dynamic obj)
{
   string one = Convert.ToString(obj.someProperty);
   string two = new string(one.Where(ch => Char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray());
}
```

It compiles and runs as expected.

Now consider same method where the operation is condensed into a single line:

```
public static void Foo(dynamic obj)
{
   string three 
       = new string(Convert.ToString(obj.someProperty)
         .Where(ch => Char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray());
}
```

This won't compile, it throws the error:

> Error CS1977  Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

However, if I cast the `Convert.ToString` part to a string, it works!

```
string three 
  = new string(((string)Convert.ToString(obj.someProperty))
    .Where(ch => Char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray());
```

Why is that cast necessary? Why doesn't Linq know that the return value of `Convert.ToString` is a string?

Comment: "Why doesn't Linq know that the return value of Convert.ToString is a string?"

Because it isn't. `dynamic` is sticky: everything you do with `dynamic` is: `dynamic` until you tell it otherwise. You and I know that `Convert.ToString` always returns a `string`, but as far as the compiler is concerned: `dynamic`